# Why an invalid form control with name javascript error in ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have  a form with few fields in php 
I am constantly getting this error

I have a ajax form in codeigniter framework which constantly gives following error

> An invalid form control with name='email' is not focusable. (index):1
>   An invalid form control with name='name' is not focusable. (index):1
>   An invalid form control with name='mobile' is not focusable. (index):1
>   An invalid form control with name='product' is not focusable.
>   (index):1 An invalid form control with name='message' is not
>   focusable.

I tried all options but nothing is getting solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have repeated your ID name in the form fields. Check whether you have given same name to more than one ID - It has to be unique.